# Casperjs: how can I submit a form that has action="#"

Tags: javascript, forms, casperjs

I am trying to get my casper to login into a website, but it has this form:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" name="logon" id="loginForm" onsubmit="DoLogin(); return false;">
```

I get this in my casper

```
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'div.mainLoginLe
ftPanel form'
[debug] [remote] Set "username" field value to foo
[debug] [remote] Set "password" field value to ***
[info] [remote] submitting form to #, HTTP POST
[warning] [remote] unable to submit form
```

How can I trigger the "`DoLogin();`" or submit the form a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run the function. Casper runs in the context of the website.

```
casper.fill('#loginForm', {/* stuff */}, false);//Note the false at the end to not submit it.

casper.evaluate(function() {
    DoLogin();
});
```

Comment: That didn't work, but helped me understand evaluate()